# Different color for different line for plot in R

Tags: r, plot, colors, legend, survival-analysis

I am trying to plot a survival curve with ten different color for ten different line, its basically the survival probability based on ten regions.

The problem right now is as the default palette number is 8, the last two will color will be repeating even if I give col=1:10 which is making it difficult for us to interpret the result.

Can I used the rainbow function here ?

```
    pdf("E:/survplot.pdf", width=10, height=10)
    plot(survfit(survobj ~ strata(region), data=rfdata,type="kaplan-meier",conf.int=FALSE),mark.time=FALSE,col=1:10,xlim=c(0,400),ylim=c(0,1),ylab="Probability", xlab="Days on Lot",main="Survival Probability") 
    legend("topright",legend = c(1:10), lty = 1, col = 1:10,title = "Regions")
    dev.off()

    palette()
    [1] "black"   "red"     "green3"  "blue"    "cyan"    "magenta" "yellow"  "gray"
```

Comment: I manually given ten colors and it worked, I am interested in any short functions which makes it easier ?

Comment: sure you can use rainbow `plot(1:10, pch = 19, col = rainbow(10))` or you can type `colors()` to get a list of all the ones in grDevices. there are other add-on packages with more (and larger) palettes [`install.packages('RColorBrewer')`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RColorBrewer/index.html) is a popular one